# Java Stream Api - is it possible to keep original map() input?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I understand the map() operation does not keep state, however there are some cases where this might be helpful, for example:

```
List<String> somePageLinks = ... //populate the list

//crawl those pages
somePageLinks.stream().map( link -> CrawlerFactory.getCrawler( link ).
                       forEach( crawler.getContent( link );
```

The problem is that "link" is no longer available for forEach(). Any way to overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to store the `link` in the instance created by `CrawlerFactory.getCrawler (link)`, so that you don't have to pass the `link` again to `crawler.getContent`.

Another way is for `map` to produce some sort of "Pair" object that contains both the `link` and the instance returned by `CrawlerFactory.getCrawler (link)`. This would make both the `link` and the `crawler` available in the `forEach` method.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, of course I could just omit the map()...

```
somePageLinks.stream().forEach( link -> {
                CrawlerFactory.getCrawler( link ).getContent( link );
            });
```

Comment: You might want to question your design. Why a the factory need the link to create the crawler and then again the link to fetch the content? Either you don't need it in the factory, or you dont' need it in the `getContent` method. If it's possible, it would be simple as `map(link -> CrawlerFactory.getCrawler().getContent(link));` or `map(link -> CrawlerFactory.getCrawler(link).getContent())`

Comment: Yep, doable as well. I wanted the crawler to be stateless (ease caching), but we can question that..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the .peek() method on a Stream, which like forEach takes a Consumer, but retains the Stream untouched. You might thus use a .peek() before a .map

```
myStream.peek(link -> consume(link)).map(link -> transform(link));
```